# PowerShell if statement gets boolean value wrong

Tags: powershell

I ran into a following problem (not exactly a problem, just something I don't understand). I have a class in Powershell that collects MAC addresses from the company network. Since there are different VLANs in the domain, I can't simply get the addresses from the ARP table, so I wrote a script that collects the MAC Addresses from the VLAN I'm in, and runs a remote command on the computers that are on a different subnet. It works perfectly, but I ran into a problem that I've never seen before.
When the MAC address of a computer isn't found in the local ARP table, my script sets the value of the MAC address `$false` and the following if statement (that calls the function to collect the MAC address from the remote machine) should run when the value of this variable is `$false`. Now, if I write the statement as `if(!$this.MACAddress)` then even though the value is `$false`, it steps through the conditional and runs like it was `$true`. If the value of the variable is empty, then it enters. If I write the statement as `if($this.MACAddress -eq $false)` it also enters the conditional, but for some reason it doesn't recognize the `!` version right. I'm not saying I'm expert at PowerShell, but I used boolean variables before, and it always worked right. What can cause it not to work as I want it to here?

A little more of the code:

```
Class NetDevice
{
  $devicename
  $MACAddress
  $IPAddress

  NetDevice($devicename)
  {
    $this.name = $devicename
    $this.IPAddres = $this.GetIPbyHostname($devicename) ## this is a method in the same class that simply gets the IP address by the provided hostname
    $this.GetMACfromARP()
    if(!$this.MACAddress) ## This is the conditional the scirpt never steps into, unless the variable is empty, or I use the full ($this.MACAddress -eq $false) form.
    {
      $this.GetMACfromADcomputer ## This is the method that invokes the command on the remote machine to get the MAC address from there
    }
  }

  GetMACfromARP()
  {
     $MAC = arp -a | ConvertFrom-String | Where-Object { $_.P2 -eq $this.IPAddress }
     if($MAC)
     {
        $this.MACAddress = $MAC.P3
     }
     else
     {
        $this.MACAddress = $false
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a little more of the script?

Comment: Try `if(!($this.MACAddress))`

Comment: Also, `$this` is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#this). Since we cannot see any context in your question, chances are you need to use a different self-defined variable name there.

Comment: I edited my original comment with some of the code.

Comment: I guess that since you have declared the class property at class scope, then the property does exist, even though its value may be $false. By using `if(!($this.MACAddress))` you let PowerShell evaluate the value of that property first (because of the extra brackets) and then test with the not operator `!`.

Comment: The issue may be caused by a blank MAC Address messes up `ConvertFrom-String` causing it to substitute a different value. Try printing the MAC address in between to see the output `ConvertFrom-String` is not my favorite command purely because of how it handles spaces.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. If I write the variable on console, it says it's false. Also the `$this.MACAddress -eq $false` kind of if statemnt works. Only the `!$this.MACAddress` kinf of one doesn't.